# How to represent a small map of integers as an array?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, dictionary, integer

Let's say I want to build a *small* simple map, where the key is N integers (fixed, usually one) and the value is M integers (also fixed, usually one).

Now I would like to store the data an an integer array, for space efficiency. I am programming in the JVM, but it should not really make a difference, unless the algorithm would require storing *pointers* as integers.

Has anyone defined a simple data structure that can do that?

[EDIT] The answers I had so far seem to show that no one understands my question, so I'll try to clarify. Firstly, forget about the M and N; just imagine I said one int key and one int value. AFAIK, if you want to use a normal HashMap where the key is an integer and the value is an integer, then you will end up with at least 2 + 3 * N objects, where N is the number of entries.

What I want to know is, can you pack all those ints *in a single array of primitive ints*, reducing your object count to two, independent of the number of keys. One for the int[], and one for the wrapper object that gives you some map-like interface. Neither my keys nor my values will ever be null. And I don't need a full standard java.util.Map implementation either. I just need, get, put, and remove, taking and returning *primitive ints* not Integer objects. Access does *not* need to be O(1), like in a normal HashMap.

Comment: How would you imagine this to be done?  Also if you strengthen the space requirement, some other property (like time or size) need to loosen.

Comment: If I knew how it went, I wouldn't ask for it. But just because I don't know how it goes does not mean that it is not possible. I am aware of the compromises. I'm talking about potentially millions of small maps.

Comment: in that case I do not understand your problem description.

Comment: I don't think anyone did. Is it clearer after my edit?

Comment: Not much.  Show some code demonstrating what you do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the answer is no, at least not in Java.

But you can simply keep your keys and your values in an int array (each) with matching indexes, and if you keep the key array sorted, you can perform a binary search.

The trouble with Java arrays though is that they're fixed size structures, so if you want to store more elements than your arrays are allocated to, reallocating them is quite expensive.

So you'll have to make a trade-off between the size of the array and the number of reallocations, maybe something similar to how `ArrayList` does it.

The other, somewhat smaller problem is that int being a primitive type, there's no null value, but you can designate a special int value to denote null.

Comment: This is similar to the previous answer, except the keys are sorted. So I get slower put, but faster gets. Really I should try both, because I don't know my put/get ratio yet.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. It would be faster on every operation, because you can't just insert at the end, you have to go over all keys to know if it is already there when doing a put.

Comment: Yes, at insert time you do the same binary search and if the key isn't already present, you shift all the entries beyond it to the right using `System.arrayCopy`. And another important difference is that two one-dimensional arrays are more efficient than one two-dimensional one.

Comment: Thats still pretty slow on puts right? Considering its an insertion sort?

Comment: @kyun Well, if you're optimizing for space, you'll always have to give up some of the speed. Of course it depends on the actual usage pattern, but generally in maps insertion speed matters less than lookup.

Comment: @biziclop - I suppose that is true generally, nicely reasoned :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the ArrayList(actually AbstractList) class has equals method overridden appropriately, you can directly use a map like so:

```
Map<List, List> map = new HashMap<List, List>();
```

Comment: I want to *save space*, and therefore I want to *not* use a normal HashMap, which creates at least one object per key, and especially not ArrayList of Integer objects, instead of arrays of primitive ints! You have totally missed my point, I'm afraid. Possibly I haven't expressed myself clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I think  I understand the problem, I'll take a shot at a solution:

The very simple way of achieving what you want is to keep a single two dimensional array `int array[NKeys][2]`, where `array[i][0]` is the key and `array[i][1]` is one of the M values. You could, then iterate the array and for every query of a `key`, return all `array[i][1]` such that `array[i][0] == key`. Of course, this works for a single int key rather than a set of int keys. Also, this is awful in complexity. I can't think of any other way of doing this without adding more Java objects/C pointers.

Comment: I like this. Simply don't do any hashing at all, and iterate over the keys. Seems like the best solution so far. Why didn't I think of that myself?

Comment: Probably because its awful complexity on gets :). But as you've already said, its a compromise you make for not using more objects.